# Is there a way to complete a mobile MFA without using a mobile number in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am looking to write some automated tests for an Azure AD B2C policy. The policy will have mobile MFA for some of the users but not all of them. The purpose of the tests is to check that the B2C policy is configured correctly and the right users are required to complete a mobile MFA in order to continue.

Is there a way to complete the mobile MFA without having to use a mobile phone either a physical mobile or using an API that can receive SMS messages?

Is there a test number and test code that can be used?

Comment: Are you using the display control or the phonefactor technical profile?

Comment: Phone factor technical profile

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test this is by using Google Voice: https://voice.google.com/about

They have a built in SMS feature that you can use to test out the MFA. Please let me know if you have any questions!